# Android - a better website launcher native app

Tags: android, launcher

I have developed a very simple Android native app to launch my HTML5 webapp.
Here is the main class:

```
package com.plancake.android.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PlancakeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://www.mywebsite.com"));  
        startActivity(viewIntent);   
    }
}
```

When I tap its icon from my homescreen the first time everything works fine: Android opens up the browser and my webapp is loaded. Lovely!

The problem arises when I leave the webbrowser and I tap again on my launcher icon from the home screen or task manager. In that case, I get just a black screen.

I think the problem is that Android calls the onResume method (or something else), anyway not the onCreate in this latter case.

I can see two solutions:
1) Either I replicate the startActivity call in all other methods, such as onStart, onRestore - but in that case I am afraid my app will create a new browser window everytime, therefore consuming a lot of memory unnecessarily
2) Or after each tap, force my launcher app to leave the memory so that the onCreate method is called everytime I tap - but in this case, even if I "kill" my app, the browser will be still open so next time I tap on my launcher icon a new browser window will be created anyway

I hope I was clear enough in describing my problem and the solutions I thought of - which either of them are ideal.

Please, I would like to know how you would suggest to solve my problem.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: have you tried calling finish() after you've fired your intent?

Comment: I would call finish() in the onPause method but Im not sure what you could do about opening another window, im not even sure if you can close a window from another application, perhaps there is a way of checking whether the window has already been opened or not

Calling finish in the onPause method will stop the black screen but Im still not sure on the window

Comment: @Espiandev Not yet. But is that anyway the way to go? Even if I kill my app, the browser will be still "alive". So when I tap the launcher icon again, a new browser window will be created, despite there is already the same window open, right?

Comment: @SmartLemon - yes, that's exactly my concern - I wouldn't like to make things too complicated, because they either easily break or have side effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onResume() method is always called after onCreate().

If you leave your activity and it is not killed by the system, then it might not be "created" again. It is left in a paused state.

What you should do is move your code to onResume() to ensure that the intent creating the webview is called every single time you enter your application

Comment: Does that mean that everytime I enter my application, a new browser window will be created?

Comment: I don't think. The problem which will arise, however, is that you have to handle what happens when you touch the back key, when you are on the browser. If the intent is in the onResume() method, it will be created. For that you should call startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult method

Comment: I see. What kind of result can I expect when firing my intent?

Comment: The result is obtained in the launching activity. Fire the intent with startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode). When the browser is finished, the onActivityResult(requestCode,...) method is called on the launching activity. Do whatever you want if the requestCodes match

Comment: Thanks MobileCushion. Is the onActivityResult method called only when the browser is closed? And anyway, how can I use the fact the browser has been closed?

Comment: onActivityResult is called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7534/discussion-between-mobilecushion-and-dan)

Comment: maybe you can also try this intent flag  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);